# How to Change Keyboard in Python PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to print out text with PyAutoGUI, and I have my keyboard set to Dvorak, so whenever I print out text, it comes out with incorrect characters. For example, "Hello World!" comes out as "Jdpps <soph!".

The same thing happens when I put the string in a variable too.

Is there a way to make it print out the text literally as I typed it?

Comment: Setting the keyboard layout us usually a feature of the OS.

Comment: Is there a way I can change it for the scope of the program though?

Answer (score 1):

So what I ended up doing was creating a file *.xkbmap-qwerty* in my home directory, and then ran **os.system("xmodmap ~/.xkbmap-qwerty")** to load the keys, and then it didn't affect my shell when the program exited, or even while the program was running.

Here's my file:

```
    keysym q = q Q
    keysym w = w W
    keysym e = e E
    keysym r = r R
    keysym t = t T
    keysym y = y Y
    keysym u = u U
    keysym i = i I
    keysym o = o O
    keysym p = p P
    keysym bracketleft = bracketleft braceleft
    keysym bracketright = bracketright braceright
    keysym a = a A
    keysym s = s S
    keysym d = d D
    keysym f = f F
    keysym g = g G
    keysym h = h H
    keysym j = j J
    keysym k = k K
    keysym l = l L
    keysym semicolon = semicolon colon
    keysym quoteright = quoteright quotedbl
    keysym z = z Z
    keysym x = x X
    keysym c = c C
    keysym v = v V
    keysym b = b B
    keysym n = n N
    keysym m = m M
    keysym comma = comma less
    keysym period = period greater
    keysym slash = slash question
    keysym 1 = 1 exclam
    keysym 2 = 2 at
    keysym 3 = 3 numbersign
    keysym 4 = 4 dollar
    keysym 5 = 5 percent
    keysym 6 = 6 asciicircum
    keysym 7 = 7 ampersand
    keysym 8 = 8 asterisk
    keysym 9 = 9 parenleft
    keysym 0 = 0 parenright
    keysym minus = minus underscore
    keysym equal = equal plus
```

Comment: Somewhat simpler (and maybe more modern): os.system("setxkbmap -layout us") or in my case I had to use the german layout.