# Hashtag being changed to a tilde in my code output?

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui, hashtag, tilde

```
import time

time.sleep(5)

pyautogui.click(1191, 880)
pyautogui.write("#hasan\n", interval=0.25)
```

I want it to print "#hasan" but when i run the code, it types "~hasan"

edit: im using ubuntu 18 and i have the United Kingdom Keyboard Layout (qwerty)

why is pyautogui correcting a hashtag to a tilde, every single time?

Comment: This is probably unreproducible without your specific machine configuration -- anyway it probably have something to do with your keyboard layout.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to Change Keyboard in Python PyAutoGUI - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734744/how-to-change-keyboard-in-python-pyautogui)

Comment: Include your operating system and display server (X on Linux? or something else) too.

Comment: @user202729 added my os to the post. looked at the other question and didnt help me out.